# How to manage files permission with SVN in Android

Tags: java, android, svn

We are developing an Android application in java, using SVN as revision control system.

I want some source files don't be shared. That is, I don't want that every developer has all source files, else it only should have the files he is working in. But I want this source files were uploaded to SVN manager.

The problem is all source files are necessary to run the app in the emulator.

In Embarcadero Delphi, I could give them only .dcu files (precompiled files), and then, they only has the source files I let them.

I don't know how could I do it in Android, and How should I manage it with SVN.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why do you want to manage it in Android ?

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you want that?

Comment: It seems to me, that this question belongs only to `svn` and not to `java` or `android`.

Comment: @Andremony the solution depends on the programming language used, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Android library project and place only the compiled class files in the JAR.
Then keep this JAR in the Subversion repository so the developers can check out and use it in their projects.